# Activity life cycle methods and Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Two different sets of life cycle methods are available : [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) and [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) life cycle methods.

If I implement Activity life cycle methods like

```
onCreate()
onStart()
```

Is there any need to implement Callback methods like

```
onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
onActivityStarted(Activity activity)
```

etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are separate things.  The `Activity.onCreate()`, `Activity.onStart()`, etc. methods are ones you override within your custom `Activity` implementation to do your application specific work.

The `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` are different and can be used for your app to track the coming/going of any `Activity` within your app.  You really have to have some special needs to use this functionality.  These are often used in libraries which use singleton instances or other components which need to know if a given `Activity` has been destroyed.  Most apps probably do not need to use these callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you explain some useful scenarios for implementing these callbacks in real time applications?

Comment: What do you mean by "real time applications"?

Comment: I will simply rephrase it to application.  After reading your answer second time, I understood it.